# array_walk_recursive doesn't seem to work

Tags: php

I want to apply a function to each element/prop of an object but it seems `array_walk_recursive()` does not work on object. i.e:

```
if( $re = $con->query("SELECT id, created_date, contents FROM " . 
                      POST_DATA . " WHERE type = 'news' ORDER BY ".
                      "created_date DESC LIMIT $amount") ) {
    if( $re->num_rows != 0 ) {
        while( $ob = $re->fetch_object() ) {
            $ob = array_walk_recursive( $ob, "_output" );
            print_r($ob);
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

would simply return '1'.

How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually returning a value of `True` for `array_walk_recursive`.  If you look at the function's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), you'll see that what this method is doing is calling the function `_output` for each item and key in the object.

You should also have some code that looks similar to this, I would imagine, to get it to work correctly:

```
function _output($data, $key) {
    echo "For the key $key, I got the data: ";
    print_r($data);
}
```

Where `_output` is called because that is the stringified name that you gave in the `array_walk_recursive` function.  That should print your values to the screen.

---

**Edit**:

It seems that I'm not actually answering what you were originally wanting to do, though.  If you're wanting to apply a function to every element of an array, I would suggest that you look at [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).  You can use `array_map` like this:

```
function double($item) {
    return 2 * $item;
}

array_map('double', $item);
```

Ultimately, if the recursion is something that you desire, you could probably do something like this:

```
function callback($key, $value) {
    // do some stuff
}

function array_map_recursive($callback, $array) {
   $new_array = array()
   foreach($array as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
          $new_array[$key] = array_map_recursive($callback, $value);
      } else {
          $new_array[$key] = call_user_func($callback, $key, $value);
      }
   }
   return $new_array;
}

array_map_recursive('callback', $obj);
```

That would return another array like $obj, but with whatever the callback was supposed to do.